# MongoDB wont let me save Object possible circular reference

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I am trying to save to the database the updated Account details object which contains a list of Player objects in it.

```
    public class AccountDetails {
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
        public String Token { get; set; }
        public int PremiumDays { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public String LastLogin { get; set; }
        public int AdminLevel { get; set; }
        public int Banned { get; set; }
        public int Muted { get; set; }
```

It seems to get this error on the Players part,

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'Maximum serialization depth exceeded (does the object being serialized have a circular reference?).'
```

I have looked through the references for Player and the inherited GameObj but I cannot seem to find what might be causing this circular reference,

This is my Player Object,

```
        public PlayerClass Class { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
        public List<ArchewoodGameServer.core.Shared.Utils.Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
        public int AttributePoints { get; set; }
        public int CurrentHealth { get; set; }
        public int MaxHealth { get; set; }
        public int CurrentMana { get; set; }
        public int MaxMana { get; set; }
        public int CurrentExp { get; set; }
        public int MaxExp { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<Node> Path = new List<Node>();
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PathCount = 0;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int HealthTick = 0, AttackTick = 10000, AnimTick = 0, MaxAnimTick = 20;
        public float AttackSpeed { get; set; }
        public ushort AttackRange { get; set; }
```

and this is my GameObj class,

```
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public int O { get; set; }
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int T { get; set; }
        public float S { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Instance Instance { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string InstanceID { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<String> playerInteractions = new List<string>();
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int LastProcessedSequence { get; set; }
        public string TargetEntity { get; set; }
        public ushort PrivateId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem in our core project on this way.

```
'
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using AutoMapper;

var stringContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_mapper.Map<DataDTO>(newdata), new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }).ToString();

 _mongoService.Save(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataDTO>(stringContent));


//mongo service save method
public async void Save(DataDTO dataDTO)
{
  await collection.InsertOneAsync(dataDTO));
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JsonIgnore] were not working with mongos parser so I changed the structure to not rely on these tags and it was resolved.